# Is there a particular way to add an appendix in the Springer LNCS format with LaTeX?

Tags: formatting, appendices, lncs, appendix

I'm required to add a **one-page appendix** to an article written in the **Springer LNCS** format, and I write on **Overleaf** (where the Springer LNCS template doesn't include appendices). Is there a specific format to do this with Springer LNCS?

If not, I assume the universal way to do this is a big word "Appendix" on the upper-left and then paragraphs as usual below? Right now I'm trying the following:

```
\usepackage{appendix}
...
...
\appendix
\section{Appendix}
```

but the appendix doesn't start on a new page, and it is compiled to be "A  Appendix" rather than "Appendix". How can I fix it?

Or if the Springer LNCS has a particular way to add an appendix, please tell me!

---

I did try some other ways using the `appendix` package, yet they all generate a separate page displaying "Appendices" and start the paragraphs on the next page, which is not allowed.

Comment: Perhaps `\clearpage\section*{Appendix}` then?

Comment: @LianTzeLim Thank you very much! I got what I imaged in my mind now. Just need to make sure this is legit in the Springer LNCS format.